# Adding path to the PATH environment variable does not work

Tags: python, pip

My pip is not being recognized by my terminal and it says it's because I don't have "C:\Users\dsmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts" is not in PATH.

However, when I go to environment variables -> system variables -> PATH -> new and add the above path in, it doesn't work. When I restart my computer, the variable is gone.

What should I do? (I have windows 10 if that helps)

Edit: I just gave up and downloaded conda for install, but that ended up fixing pip for some reason. thank you for all the help!

Comment: But python is being reconigzed at terminal? Have you tried to [install pip](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-pip-windows)?

Comment: If you don't have much to lose, reinstall python and check the "Add to Path" option in the installation settings.

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem, but someone here is having a similar issue https://superuser.com/questions/1193856/windows-10-environment-path-variables-missing-after-reboot

Comment: Pip is installed. I even went to the python installation change and checked that pip is checked. When I go to python/scripts, pip is there.

Comment: Ok, if you don't have much to lose, as @Qudus said, [reinstall python](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-python-3-windows).

Comment: @minnieswiftie initiate `pip` as   `python -m pip`

Answer (score 0):

verify pip installation :

```
pip help
```

- if got error means pip is not installed, do installation step
- if got a similar message :

  pip 18.0 from c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip

  then it's already installed

pip installation on windows:

1. download file from **get-pip.py** [download it from here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)
2. save the file in site-packages
3. In cmd prompt go to **get-pip.py** folder location
4. run the command "`python get-pip.py`"

Also check on how to configure environment variables [here](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-do-i-set-system-variable-path-for-python-on-windows/) and pip installation [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

If still not working, please cross check each and every point in the sequence order.

Comment: Nah I have pip downloaded. It works when I do python -m pip install <PACKAGE> but doesn't work when I do pip install.